# Array.sort not sorting all element

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I know there must be some hidden things here, as it's doesn't seems to be fair at all. Thanks for any help!

`String[] bankNotesValue = scan.nextLine().split(" ");
java.util.Arrays.sort(bankNotesValue,Collections.reverseOrder());
//input 10 4 8 5`

```
output : [8, 5, 4, 10]
```

Comment: Are you expecting `String`s to appear in descending, numerical order?

Comment: :(  oh man sorry! Thanks

Comment: No problem, haha. Just be sure to convert the `String`s to `int`s first.